# AsyncTask never ends in onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an AsyncTask which read JSONArray in the doInBackground Method and return an ArrayList of custom Items (ArrayList). Before this, in the onPostExecute method i move the ArrayList charged in the AsyncTask to another ArrayList of the Main thread, but i think that my AsyncTask never ends and still working. Here I put my code:

Here the AsyncTask:

```
private class ReadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Item>>{

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Item> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayList<Item> auxList = new ArrayList<Item>();
            LoadData(auxList); //Method that reads JSON and load information in the ArrayList
            return auxList; // Return ArrayList
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Item> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.i("OnPostExecute", String.valueOf(result.size()));  //The size of the array
            listMain = result; // Move the data of the AsyncTask to the main Thread

            Log.i("OnPostExecute", String.valueOf(listaComic.size()));  //The size of the ArrayList I use in the Main Thread
        }

    }
```

Here the call to the AsyncTask in the Main Thread:

```
if (isOnline()){    //Return true if there is internet connection
    ReadJSONTask task = new ReadJSONTask();
    task.execute();

    Log.i("Main Thread - listMain Size", String.valueOf(listMain.size())); //Never executed

    //This for loop its only for debug purposes, never executed
    for (Item item : listMain){ 
        Log.i("Items", item.toString());
    }
}
```

In the log i see that all Log in the onPostExecute() method are printed, but nothing from the Main Thread.

I don't know where is the error to fix it, i have been working on it 2 days and searching in forums, here in StackOverflow and i can't fix that :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As name indicates `AsyncTask` is **asynchronous**, but you for some reason expects `execute()` to be blocked unless async task ends, which is wrong. Your code works fine and I expect listMain to simply be empty and once `execute()` fires asynctask, `for` would show nothing because async task is not done yet. You should rework your app logic, so async task could tell "main thread" it finished. I.e. move your `for` loop to separate method and call it from `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I have improved another algorithm for the Asynctask and now it works, thank you for teach me this lesson, it's my first AsyncTask and I didn't have the correct approach about this. Thanks :)